# Batch Automation to change text

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a .CAD file where I need to append static data "NH,NHNOKYCDATAONRECORD" after checking the .NAK file.

NAK file contains row numbers which indicated on which row number NH,NHNOKYCDATAONRECORD text to be appended appears in the .CAD file.

The code is absolutely working fine when I mention the row numbers in the batch file and execute it, however it would not work if I don't mention the row numbers in the batch file. Any idea what would be the issue?

**CAD File Format:**

```
099,3,IRE,100040148,,TEN,RENNY,1100/,EI,6637032796,6700.00,B
099,3,IRE,100042714,,TEN,SABAM,1100/,EI,8449185754,4700.00,B
099,3,IRE,100044249,,TEN,ELVERTHY,1100/,EI,8890949716,1300.00,A
099,3,IRE,100063520,,TEN,PAUL,1100/,EI,8579431077,2000.00,A
099,3,IRE,100065012,,TEN,BAL INVRA,1100/,EI,9087430395,5900.00,A
099,3,IRE,100065137,,TEN,YANA AMIER,1100/,EI,6651639385,5000.00,A
099,3,IRE,100065343,,TEN,SHAWN,1100/,EI,9087430395,5900.00,A
099,3,IRE,100066754,,TEN,NEIL,1100/,NH,NHNOKYCDATAONRECORD,5000.00,A
099,3,IRE,100066820,,TEN,PAT JOJO,1100/,EI,8715858324,1000.00,A
```

**NAK File Format:**

```
AHR,ACCPWEXP,ADCAD099100001180706102746.CAD,CAD1807060000129
DER,001145,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001195,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001197,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001233,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001260,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001262,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001322,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID 
DER,001351,CAD-SEC-10,10-NUMBER IS NOT VALID
```

Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Documents\CAD"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Documents\CAD"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\*.CAD"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\*.NAK"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\ADCAD099100001%date:~-2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.CAD"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

:: Retrieve line numbers from file2.

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 REM token 1 (%%a) must be "DER", token 2 (%%b) contains line number
 REM set 'line' to zero-suppressed line number, then #linenumber to 'Y'

 ECHO "%%a" "%%b"

 IF "%%a"=="DER" SET /a line=1%%b %% 100000&SET "#!line!=Y"
)
REM The next line should list all of the lines-required-to-be-changed
REM in the format "#linenumber=Y"
SET #1145=Y
SET #1195=Y
SET #1197=Y
SET #1233=Y
SET #1260=Y
SET #1262=Y
SET #1322=Y
SET #1351=Y
(
REM number each line in [] with 'find'
REM then tokenise - %%a gets the number, %%b the line-contents
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|find /n /v ""') DO (
 IF DEFINED #%%a (
  REM process if selected
  ECHO Line %%a found for analysis>con
  FOR /f "tokens=1-9,*delims=," %%g IN ("%%b") DO (
   REM Tokenise to %%g..%%p.
   REM if %%n is "EI" then replace else report
   IF "%%n"=="EI" (
    ECHO Line %%a has EI in required column and should be changed>con
    ECHO %%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,,%%k,%%l,%%m,NH,NHNOKYCDATAONRECORD,%%p
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO Line %%a does not have EI in required column>con
    ECHO ERROR - line %%a does NOT contain EI IN required column LINE OMITTED
   )
  )
 ) ELSE IF "%%b" neq "" (
  REM IF NOT selected, simply regurgitate it unless empty
  ECHO %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: It is really not very clear what your issue is. Which part of your batch file is not working?

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: the batch doesn't change **NH,NHNOKYCDATAONRECORD** whereever required unless I manually put row numbers in the batch and run it. I want the batch to autorun and change the text into particular rows according to .NAK file data.

Comment: Then read the NAK data file with another for loop and set the appropriate variables.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 2):

This part of your batch doesn't work correctly,
(what you'd discovered yourself when executing it in an open cmd window and inserted a pause command).

```
:: Retrieve line numbers from file2.
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 REM token 1 (%%a) must be "DER", token 2 (%%b) contains line number
 REM set 'line' to zero-suppressed line number, then #linenumber to 'Y'
 ECHO "%%a" "%%b"
 IF "%%a"=="DER" SET /a line=1%%b %% 100000&SET "#!line!=Y"
)
```

Reason is that

```
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
```

expects a single file to open, but `%filename2%` contains a wildcard `C:\Users\Documents\CAD\*.NAK`

Solution is to put another (simple) for around this section to iterate the files

```
:: Retrieve line numbers from file2.
For %%F in ("%filename2%") Do (
    FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%%F") DO (
        REM token 1 (%%a) must be "DER", token 2 (%%b) contains line number
        REM set 'line' to zero-suppressed line number, then #linenumber to 'Y'
        ECHO "%%a" "%%b"
        IF "%%a"=="DER" SET /a line=1%%b %% 100000&SET "#!line!=Y"
    )
)
Set #
```

Sample output:

```
> SU_1337246.cmd
"AHR" "ACCPWEXP"
"DER" "001145"
"DER" "001195"
"DER" "001197"
"DER" "001233"
"DER" "001260"
"DER" "001262"
"DER" "001322"
"DER" "001351"
#1145=Y
#1195=Y
#1197=Y
#1233=Y
#1260=Y
#1262=Y
#1322=Y
#1351=Y
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, as a (quite) new user you should take the [tour]. If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote)